# Drop event in dojo not not working with dojo/on

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to create a drag and drop list using dojo.The dragging and dropping works fine but when I try to write any functionality after firing DndDrop,DragStart and similar events related to drag and drop using dojo/query and dojo/on...event is not handled.Again..click event for the same NodeList works fine.Kindly spot out my mistake please.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>clac</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calcdojo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li id="operand1" class="container dropArea"></li>
        <li id="operator1" class=" container dropArea"></li>
        <li id="operand2" class=" container dropArea"></li>
        <li id="result"></li>
    </ul>   

    <ul id="sourcelist" class="container"> 
    </ul>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require(["dojo/dom-style","dojo/dom-construct","dojo/dnd/Source","dojo/dnd/Source","dojo/query","dojo/on","dojo/domReady!"],function(domStyle,domConstruct,Source,Source,query,on){
                var sourcelist = new Source('sourcelist',{accept:[""]});
                sourcelist.copyOnly = true;
                sourcelist.insertNodes(false,[
                {data: "1",type:["operand"]},
                {data: "2",type:["operand"]},
                {data: "3",type:["operand"]},
                {data: "+",type:["operator"]}]);

                var operand1 = new Source('operand1',{accept:["operand"]});
                var operand2 = new Source('operand2',{accept:["operand"]});
                var operator1 = new Source('operator1',{accept:["operator"]});

                var dropArea = query(".dropArea");
                dropArea.on("DndDrop",function(event){
                  event.preventDefault();
                  console.log("dropped");
                });

            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

(My need in here is to display "dropped")

Comment: is there an error that you can share? Also, you want to display "dropped" but before that, you are stopping the event so how will the console.log("dropped") get executed?

Comment: I'm sry about that mistake...I have now edited the code.And there is no error that is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is that the "onDrop" event does not exist for the dom nodes in the dropArea nodeList.

Below a modified source that does what you need (display "dropped") for the operand1 target:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>clac</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calcdojo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="targetList" class="container">
        <li id="operand1" class="container dropArea"></li>
        <li id="operator1" class=" container dropArea"></li>
        <li id="operand2" class=" container dropArea"></li>
        <li id="result"></li>
    </ul>   

    <ul id="sourcelist" class="container"> 
    </ul>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require(["dojo/dom-style","dojo/dom-construct","dojo/dnd/Source","dojo/dnd/Target","dojo/query","dojo/on", "dojo/aspect", "dojo/domReady!"],function(domStyle,domConstruct,Source,Target,query,on, aspect){
                var sourcelist = new Source('sourcelist',{accept:[""]});
                sourcelist.copyOnly = true;
                sourcelist.insertNodes(false,[
                {data: "1",type:["operand"]},
                {data: "2",type:["operand"]},
                {data: "3",type:["operand"]},
                {data: "+",type:["operator"]}]);

                var operand1 = new Target('operand1',{accept:["operand"]});
                var operand2 = new Target('operand2',{accept:["operand"]});
                var operator1 = new Target('operator1',{accept:["operator"]});

                //var dropArea = query(".dropArea");
                //dropArea.on("DndDrop",function(event){
                //on(operand, "onDrop",function(){
                aspect.after(operand1, "onDrop",function(){
                   console.log("dropped");
                });

            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using dojo/on - statement `on(operand, "onDrop",function(){`that I commented out - which did not work. I think this is because although the documentation calls onDrop an event of the dojo/DnD Source class, it is in fact a method of the class hence the use of target.after.
See [here](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2014/03/26/dojo-faq-what-is-the-difference-between-dojoon-and-dojoaspect/) for a discussion on the difference between dojo/on and dojo/target.

You will have to repeat this for the other targets.

(I also changed the duplicated "dojo/dnd/Source" / Source require parameter association to "dojo/dnd/Target" / Target).

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Jean-Claude Hujeux.
sourcelist.on("DndDrop",function(source,nodes,copy,target));works fine for me now.As you have mentioned that the drop operation goes on for the source and not for the target.Would be great if you could apply the dojo/aspect for the nodelist...instead of single nodes

Comment: Good! I had confused 'onDrop' and 'DndDrop' in my answer, which then is incorrrect. What really happens is that the onMouseUp event publishes the dojo topic 'dnd/drop', which Source.onDndDrop subscribes to.